# Can I set the connection time zone automatically in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I connect to a MySQL DB using MySQL Workbench (I have version 6.3), I want the **connection** to **automatically** use a different time zone than the server default.  I do not want to (and in this case cannot) change the server time zone.

I know that I can manually change the time zone using `SET time_zone = America/Chicago` after I connect, but I want this to automatically happen when I connect.

Comment: check this [article](https://oak.dev/2020/03/06/mysql-workbench-8-0-set-the-default-time-zone/) it may helps

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, but that seems like it lets you change the server settings. The official documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-instance-options-file.html corroborates this. So, again, I am not talking about changing the server settings, just the connection.